# How do I cast a method group to an object? "Cannot convert method group 'XXX' to non-delegate type 'object'."

Tags: c#

Occasionally I run into the problem of needing to execute a generic method without knowing its type.

I know I can do this each time using reflection, however I am trying to write a helper method:

```
public static object InvokeGeneric<T>(this T @this, 
    Expression<Func<T, object>> method, 
    Type genericType, 
    params object[] arguments)
{
    // I think I know what to do here
    // look at the expression tree, grab 
    // the method info, do the 
    // reflection in here, etc.
    return null;
}
```

So that I can do this:

```
this._myService.InvokeGeneric(
    e => e.MyGenericMethod, // interface IMyService { void MyGenericMethod<T>(T t); }
    typeof(MyGenericType),
    myArg);
```

However I am getting this error: Cannot convert method group 'XXX' to non-delegate type 'object'.

**Without changing my calling syntax, how can I change my method signature of my helper method to do what I want?**

***EDIT:***

I got it down to:

```
this._myService.InvokeGeneric<IMyService, object, MyArgType>(e => e.MyGenericMethod, typeof(MyGenericType), myArg);
```

The downside (besides extra typing) is that you'd need an overload for each generic variation of `Func<>` and `Action<>` that you'd want to support.

```
public static object InvokeGeneric<T, T1>(this object @this, Expression<Func<T, Action<T1>>> method, Type genericType, params object[] arguments)
{ }    

public static object InvokeGeneric<T, T1, T2>(this object @this, Expression<Func<T, Action<T1, T2>>> method, Type genericType, params object[] arguments)
{ }
```

etc.  I'm going to use that solution, but if anyone has something that meets the briefer syntax let me know and I'll accept it.  Reading a bit about method groups made me realize my syntax is ambiguous, potentially, if there are overloads, meaning a strongly-typed one like this is probably better, anyway.

Comment: Should that be `e => e.MyGenericMethod()`?

Comment: That's what pops up on Google when you Google that error message normally but no, I don't want to pass in the result of that method; I want to pass in the method into `InvokeGeneric`.  That said, I could call the method with bogus arguments and ignore them and just grab the method info, which is what you're going towards, but that's potentially a lot of typing.  I think this syntax is most concise.

Comment: You cannot assign a method to an object, but could do `Action<YourType> = e.MyGenericMethod` instead. Still, it is not a requested solution.

Comment: @AlexD See my edit; not sure if that's what you meant, or not.  But it's what I'm going with.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: I haven't gotten it to work, but you might be able to create a Delegate from the method group.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared I meant something like possible replacing `object` in `Expression<Func<T, object>>` with a proper `Action`, to get rid of "Cannot convert method group..." error. This is pretty much what you did. But I didn't see a way to make things work without modifying the caller's side.

Comment: What is the second parameter for in `InvokeGeneric`? If you would like to avoid typing and you need to pass a method name, why don't you simply pass string?

Comment: Also why are you opposed to "changing my calling syntax"?

Comment: And finally, this `this._myService.InvokeGeneric(e => e.MyGenericMethod,typeof(MyGenericType),myArg)` to me looks equivalent of this `this._myService.MyGenericMethod(myArgs)`, so it's completely unclear what you are trying to achieve. And that's probably why you don't have that many answers showing up.

Comment: @zespri The second parameter, `Type` is the actual generic type parameter to use in the generic method from the first parameter.  Using a lambda instead of a string will make the code more resilient to renames/refactorings.  I knew I could get it working by changing the syntax.  I was wondering if it was possible without doing so.  As far as those two being equivalent, yes, I was trying to execute a generic method using syntax that would be somewhat resilient to refactoring but still let me decide the generic type through a `Type` object instead of explicitly.

Comment: By second, I meant second counting 'this' parameter, so that would be 'method' sorry for being unclear.